# ObjC - how to catch and rescue an exception in a different thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

I'm building an app that uses a commercial third-party SDK for reading barcodes. The reader runs in the background, in it's own thread, which the SDK creates. As part of the setup, you assign a delegate that gets called whenever the SDK detects a valid barcode.

The problem is that the SDK occasionally throws an exception. I can see exactly where the problem is from the crash log, but since part of the SDK is compiled, I can't fix it.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
```

While I wait for the SDK vendor to fix the problem, I was wondering if it is possible for my code to catch and rescue the exception?

Any ideas, much appreciate.

Comment: No, since this is not an Objective-C exception, but a segmentation fault. Tell the writer of the library to fix their code. (Or, are you using the library erroneously, not in compliance with the documentation, by accident?)

Comment: No, it seems to be a problem with one of the barcode decoders. The SDK can auto-detect lots of different codes. The app uses 3 different codes, two of which you can read all day long without problem, but the third type crashes the SDK after just a few reads.

Comment: As @H2CO3, you'll need the library author to fix it.  That isn't an exception.  It is a fatal crash. There is no recovery mechanism.